# Openstack, devstack installation ERROR: openstackclient.shell Exception

Tags: openstack, devstack

I'm not sure if it's the right place for my question, I am trying to install devstack but I'm getting these errors:

```
openstackclient.shell Exception
2015-04-21 16:22:04.991 | ERROR: openstackclient.shell Exception raised: (six 1.7.3 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.9.0'), set(['oslo.i18n', 'oslo.utils', 'cliff'])) 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.014 | + ADMIN_TENANT= 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.015 | ++ openstack user create admin --project '' --email admin@example.com --password openstack 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.015 | ++ grep ' id ' 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.018 | ++ get_field 2 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.018 | ++ read data 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.447 | ERROR: openstackclient.shell Exception raised: (six 1.7.3 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.9.0'), set(['oslo.i18n', 'oslo.utils', 'cliff'])) 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.466 | + ADMIN_USER= 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.467 | ++ openstack role create admin 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.468 | ++ grep ' id ' 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.469 | ++ get_field 2 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.469 | ++ read data 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.897 | ERROR: openstackclient.shell Exception raised: (six 1.7.3 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.9.0'), set(['oslo.i18n', 'oslo.utils', 'cliff'])) 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.916 | + ADMIN_ROLE= 
2015-04-21 16:22:05.916 | + openstack role add --project --user 
2015-04-21 16:22:06.349 | ERROR: openstackclient.shell Exception raised: (six 1.7.3 (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('six>=1.9.0'), set(['oslo.i18n', 'oslo.utils', 'cliff'])) 
2015-04-21 16:22:06.368 | + exit_trap 
2015-04-21 16:22:06.368 | + local r=1 
2015-04-21 16:22:06.368 | ++ jobs -p 
2015-04-21 16:22:06.368 | + jobs= 
2015-04-21 16:22:06.369 | + [[ -n '' ]] 
2015-04-21 16:22:06.369 | + exit 1
```

After some research, typing pip install --upgrade setuptools, but that doesn't work I am using ubuntu 14.10 with no Virtual Machine, Please help?

Comment: What version of six do you have installed? It looks like you are using 1.7.3, and 1.9.0 is required at least.

python -c 'import six;print six.__version__'

Comment: Thank's for the reply, I'm new to openstack so I just followed the getting started tutorial on dev stack by git clone devstack stable/icehouse, dowloading the locarc.sh and then run ./stack.sh, and get stack there with these errors.

Comment: The version of six is 1.9.0

Comment: Is there any reason why are you using the Icehouse release instead of Juno, or even latest changes from trunk?

Comment: No, so do you advice to use juno?

Comment: That's the best option to use latest stable release. Most of my time I'm using trunk version of OpenStack components, because want to be up-to-date with the changes (still it's pretty unstable dev environment). If you can pick Juno that would be great. Just one more thing - there is one week left and the OpenStack Kilo release will be available.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser but I've tried juno and I'm facing a new exception now !:(    home/varun/devstack/tools/worlddump.py World dumping... see ./worlddump-2014-12-23-203304.txt for details + exit 1

Answer (score 0):

For the original question, you have version 1.7.3 of six but 1.9.0 is needed.  Uninstall six (pip uninstall six), then uninstall devStack (./clean.sh), then re-install devStack (./stack.sh)--but I'd recommend installing Kilo.
As for the "worlddump.py" output, that is just a dump of the state when an error occurs.  The actual error will be in the text above this.